# Perl-Application and queries with accented characters using postgres

Tags: mysql, apache, postgresql, perl, dbd-pg

It's been a decade I have worked with Postgres and Perl.

One of my oldest still-operated applications, an dictionary of government addresses and departmental responsibilities, has issues handling query terms containing accented characters, for example `köln`. In other words, whenever a query term contains a accented character (mainly umlauts) there are 0 results returned.

I have to mention that this behavior is only happening using this application with Postgres as the database. If I switch to MySQL5 (same data) same queries are working correctly.

Trying to track the cause of this problem I have checked the following:

- Postgres database is UTF-8 (using the command `show server_encoding;`)
- Postgres client encoding is also UTF8 (using `show client_encoding;`)
- If I use the Postgres monitor and execute the same SQL query as the application does, using accented characters in the query term, I get correct results
- The Perl application itself is handling UTF-8, the HTML-Header is set correctly, contents of the output display correct and not garbled
- All Perl code files, scripts, .pm package files and templates are UTF-8 encoded (I verified that with `file --mime perl_file_name`)
- I fiddled with the database connection, setting `$self->{dbh}->{pg_enable_utf8} = 1;` or/and `$self->{dbh}->do("SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';");` or/and `$self->{dbh}->do("SET NAMES 'UTF8';");` with no change
- I've updated the `DBD::Pg module` to version 3.6.2, no change.

So I am pretty much out of ideas what else to check or try to get Postgres fully working. Like mentioned in my intro, same application just using MySQL as database works flawlessly.

2 years ago the application was changed to handle UTF-8 data, I did not do the changes myself, but as far as I can see in the code (compared to the code in my GIT repo) its just the HTML UTF8-Header `print "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";` and a few unrelated template parts. Perhaps that change somewhere is the origin for all the problems but I don't know what esp. to adjust for Postgres.

The current Perl version is 5.22.1, using Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu). The vhost configuration is simple:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
ScriptAlias /...abs-path-to-app.../cgi-bin/
<Directory "/...abs-path-to-app.../cgi-bin/">
     AllowOverride None
     Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
     <IfVersion < 2.4>
         Allow from all
     </IfVersion>
     <IfVersion >= 2.4>
         Require all granted
     </IfVersion>
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Postgres is version 9.1.24.

**Edit:**

`Collate` and `Ctype` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`, `Encoding` is set to `UTF-8` for the database in question.
Taking a look into the tables, all `character varying` columns use `pg_catalog."default"` collation. Executing `show lc_collate;` show already mentioned `en_US.UTF-8`.

**Edit2:**

Using the `DBD::Pg` flag `pg_enable_utf8` and setting it to `0` seems to work out and I get the expected results. Using a value other than `0`, for example '-1`or`1` does not work. I tried out that flag (once again) right after the database connect. Actually I have to verify this as I still do not really understand what's going on.

Comment: What locales and collations are specified for the PostgreSQL database, schemas and tables?

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto: Please see my edit, hope this helps. First I thought to fiddle a bit with the field collations. But as it is UTF8 already and executing queries with the psql monitor find records using accented characters queries I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/02/dbdpg-utf-8-perl-postgresql.html

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto: Thanks, interesting article though. But as stated in my check-list, I have DBD Pg > 3.0 installed so there shouldn't be an issue and no need with addt. flags. I also checked that test script illustrated in the article and it seems to work out.